# MVC3 dynamically update a div with a child action on control event

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Currently I have a main view that is composed of several partial views like this:

...

Some of the partial views, are rendered using Html.RenderAction and some are from @sections.

Now 1 of the page has tabular data view with record list. I want to add a dropbox that has the number of records to be displayed and on change of that dropbox I want it to trigger a request that would re-render the partial-view for the list. Is that possible?

Regards,
czetsuya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include that partial view in a div. Assign an event to the dropbox using jQuery to make an ajax call to update a div onsuccess
See:
http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html
in that example though they use

```
$(".city").html(html);
```

I prefer you name your element name="city" and instead do:

```
$("#city").html(html);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where is the part where the Child Action is called? I tried adding it inside the select's change event but won't work. Is there a more seamless way to do this? Perhaps only using c# classes?

Comment: there is no current way with just c# as there is no built in server side binding in mvc for dropdowns. In the link I sent there is a call to .ajax - in there you put the link to your action or use @Url.Action(....) to form the address for the url parameter in the .ajax call.